# pointer to array or array of pointers

Tags: c++, naming-conventions

I felt confused when I saw this:

```
double *array[];
```

Is that an array of pointers to a double? Or is it a pointer to an array of doubles?

Comment: Actually `std::array` is _reserved_. It defines an array of `double*` pointers of unspecified length. Effectively that's the same as `double** array;`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Comments like that are where the myth that "arrays are pointers" get started!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is an array of pointers to double.

A pointer to array of 10 of doubles would have been written as

```
double (*array)[10];
```

It is important to understand how to read `C` pointer declarations, see e.g.

http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-reading-complex-pointer-expression/